# HTML: How to align my video on right and place text on the left?

Tags: html, css, html5-video

I have the following code in my html file:

```
  <video 
     src="finalvid.mp4"
     preload="auto"
     width="320"             
     heigth="240"
     align="right"             
     controls
     loop>
  </video>
```

Firstly, I'm trying to align it on the right. Obviously the  align="right"  part doesn't work (probably it doesn't belong there). I was searching for the video tag to put in the css file, but I didn't find something. 
Secondly, I want to place a paragraph on the left of the video.  Basically, to have something like 2 columns, the first one (left) is the text, and the second one (right) is the video.

Comment: you can do that with 'flex'

Comment: take a parent div and apply a styles into it like `display: flex; justify-content: space-between`. then take a child div and place your element tag of your text and your video tag respectively.

Comment: You spelled `height` wrong and `align` is both obsolete and not a `video` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap each side in a block element (ex. div, section, etc.) then wrap them with a "flex container" which is an element with `display:flex`. A flex container will place its children in a row by default.

### Demo

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0
}

.main {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.section {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
}

video {
  width: 100%;
  height: 56.25%;
  margin-top: 21.875%;
}
```

```html
<main class='main'>

  <section class='left section'>

    <p>But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing pleasure and praising pain was born and I will give you a complete account of the system, and expound the actual teachings of the gre</p>

  </section>
  <section class='right section'>

    <video src='http://media6000.dropshots.com/photos/1381926/20170326/005611.mp4' controls></video>

  </section>

</main>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add `float: right` and it will gonna work.